# Powershell Scripting - Select-String

Tags: powershell

I have a text file in the format as below:

```
Demo
1
2
3
[[1]]
[[2]]
```

In a Powershell script, I'm trying to find the first line number where the string matches [[.

```
$path = 'C:\Demo\Test.txt'
$pattern = "Demo"
$LineNumber = Select-String $path -Pattern $pattern | Select-Object LineNumber
```

The above code returns the line number 1 as @{LineNumber=1}

But I'm mainly interested to get the line number where it starts from [[. How do I achieve this, the script fails if I use [[ in the pattern.

Kindly help, thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `-Pattern` uses a regular expression by default. `[` has a special meaning in regular expressions so needs to be escaped (using `\`):

`Select-String input.txt -Pattern "\[\[" | Select-Object LineNumber`

Alternatively pass the `-SimpleMatch` parameter to treat `-Pattern` as a string instead:

`Select-String input.txt -Pattern "[[" -SimpleMatch | Select-Object LineNumber`

Reference docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6